# How do I get a list of all php fpm pools from command line?

Tags: php, monitoring, system-administration, fpm

We run our own monitoring, manager panels and python fabric scripts.

I cannot find any native method apart from a "ps" output parsing [1] commandline fu.

The more pool information retrieved the better (user, stat, timeout, ...)

The first plan is to parse pool.d ini files and php-fpm.conf includes in python and use that info.

Am I overlooking something else more easy or obvious?

1: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/13901/list-php-fpm-pools-by-total-cpu-usage

Comment: Tested commandlinefu in more servers and output is missing some less active pools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least, you can use:

**to list all processes of php-fpm pools:**

```
sudo service php7.4-fpm status
```

**for detailed info about running php-fpm pools**

```
sudo php-fpm{php-ver} -tt
```

for exmaple:

```
sudo php-fpm7.4 -tt
```

**Also, you can see the running PHP service by:**

```
sudo systemctl list-units | grep fpm
```

**To get pool info for all installed php versions, you can use this function:**

```
function ShowPHPInfo {

    declare -a allLines_ia
    readarray -t allLines_ia < <(sudo systemctl list-units -t service --full --all --plain --no-legend | grep fpm | awk -v col1=1 -v col2=2 -v col3=3 '{print $col1, $col2, $col3}')
    for i in "${!allLines_ia[@]}"; do
        serviceRow=${allLines_ia[i]}
        serviceName=${serviceRow%.*}        
        echo -e "$serviceRow ==========================\n\n"
        service "$serviceName" status
    done

}
```